# How to fix: HTTP request with exhaustMap operator working only once

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have button that invokes HTTP request and gets data from the server.
Now I want to stops multiple clicking on that button when until previous HTTP request is not done.

I could achieve this result by using exhaustMap operator from RXJS library.

In result its working only on first click and after HTTP request is done with success or error on another click its not working at all.

How I can resolve this problem ?

HTML

```
<button #rescheduleButton  type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
     Get Data                
</button>
```

TYPESCRIPT

```
@ViewChild('rescheduleButton', {static: false}) rescheduleButton: ElementRef;
clicks$: Observable<any>;



public ngAfterViewInit() {
    const button = this.rescheduleButton.nativeElement;
    this.clicks$ = fromEvent(button, 'click');
    this.clicks$.pipe(
        exhaustMap(() => this.slotService.getAllAvailableSlots())
    ).subscribe((slots) => {
        console.log(slots, 'slots');
    })}
```

Comment: Not related, but why are you using nativeElement here, why not just attach a click event to the button? You seem to do it a bit backwards and your code isn't really "angularish"

Comment: Okay, if you have another solution how to do Observable from your button click just say I'll replace it

Comment: Do you need to make button click as observable? Cannot you just call `this.slotService.getAvailableSlots()` when button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

add a repeat operator at the end and don't forget to handle error

```
 this.clicks$.pipe(
        exhaustMap(() => this.slotService.getAllAvailableSlots()),
        catchError(e=>of(e)),
        repeat()
    )
```

Comment: @Clarchik it's better practice to move error handling with `catchError` into your service. This way you also don't need to use `repeat()`.

Comment: Ya I think in theory ur event should still fire if error caught in the inner observable

Comment: But got another problem. When i get HTTP error next method is invoked instead of error method in subscribe

Comment: Yes that’s actually expected behavior. It is better to handle the error in catch error. As there maybe multiple inner streams in ur main stream.

Comment: Did that. But anyway its invokes succes result which shouldn't.

Comment: after throwError operator it works as before only once.

Comment: @FanCheung just help me please )))

Comment: Read the article pasted above. There is different error handling strategy in RxJs. The answer provided is the one I prefer which is not to leak error to subscribe

Comment: @Fan Cheung Couldn’t find solution for my problem? Can you help ?

Comment: Think I have provided enough information for u to solve the problem. If u still stuck please setup a stackbliz

Comment: Can;t see what's wrong with your code. Again if you use catchError there is no need to add error callback inside subscribe() because it suppose to be handled in catchError