# exhaustMap calling service only once, even after subsequent next() calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

component.ts:

```
export class TreeSearchComponent {
  searchPath = '';
  subtreeData: SubtreeDTO | null = null;
  searchPathSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('test');

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchPathSubject$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      exhaustMap((path: string) => {
          return this.nodeService.getSubtree(path)
      })
    ).subscribe({ next: (value) => this.subtreeData = value, error: (err) => { console.log(err) } });
  }

  constructor(private nodeService: NodeService) { }
}
```

template.html:

```
<label for="nodePath">Enter Node Path:</label>
<input id="nodePath" type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchPath" (ngModelChange)="searchPathSubject$.next($event)" />
<tree-display [subtreeData]="subtreeData"></tree-display>
```

service.ts:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NodeService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSubtree(path: string): Observable<SubtreeDTO> {
    return this.http.get<SubtreeDTO>(`${this.apiUrl}/nodes/subtree/${path}`);
  }
}
```

`this.nodeService.getSubree()` is only being called once upon `searchPathSubject$` initialization with `test` as value. No subsequent call to `searchPathSubject$.next()` from template calls `this.nodeService.getSubree()`.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884842/how-to-fix-http-request-with-exhaustmap-operator-working-only-once

Answer (score 0):

`exhaustMap` won't trigger again if an error has occured on a previous call.

Handle error cases, can be done in the service:

```
 private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  getSubtree(path: string): Observable<SubtreeDTO> {
    return this.http.get<SubtreeDTO>(`${this.apiUrl}/nodes/subtree/${path}`).pipe(catchError(this.handleError<SubtreeDTO>('getSubtree', {})));
  }
```